# eclipse is closing automatically

Tags: eclipse, jvm

An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
 Internal Error (4E4D4554484F440E4350500529), pid=3164, tid=212
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_22-b03 mixed mode)

Comment: can anyone help me what to do ?

Comment: Please add some additional information. Does this error happen when you do something specific or at random? Also what version of Eclipse and which OS do you use? Also it seems that you are running Eclipse on JRE 1.5, does this error occur also when you use newer JRE?

Comment: when i use the clean option in project(dynamic web project) icon then it starts cleaning and automatically it is closing .. never happen to me this kind of problem

Comment: Paste more info including debug trace. You can find the log at workspace/.metadata/.log 
Also add eclipse version, os details. Also look for hs_err* file if there was jvm crash and paste the content.

Comment: The above text is from hs_err*  file .. Is windows7 64 bit ..eclipse Luna ..jdk 1.5 ..

Comment: Those 3 lines don't tell anything. Do paste the complete backtrace in the first place while asking the question to avoid roundtrips getting your question right